# boost::unordered_map support by gcc

Tags: gcc, boost, unordered-map

When unoreded_map support was added to gcc?

I'm using gcc 4.1.1 shipped with RHEL 5.3. 
It looks like unoreded_map is missing. Is there a way to add it manually?

Answer (score 8):

gcc doesn't have `boost::unordered_map` — it is part of [Boost](http://www.boost.org/). It has `std::tr1::unordered_map`. It is included at least since 4.0.

To use `std::tr1::unordered_map`, include this header:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
```

The interface of `boost::unordered_map` and `std::tr1::unordered_map` should be similar since the latter is created from the former.

Comment: If you have C++0x support enabled, you can just #include <unordered_map>

Answer (score 2):

On older gcc versions, you could also use a hash_map, which might be "good enough".

```
#include <ext/hash_map> // Gnu gcc specific!
...

// allow the gnu hash_map to work on std::string
namespace __gnu_cxx {
   template<> struct hash< std::string > {
      size_t operator()(const std::string& s) const {
         return hash< const char* >()( s.c_str() );
      }
   }; /* gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2002-04/msg00107.html */
}

// this is what we would love to have:
typedef __gnu_cxx::hash_map<std::string, int> Hash;
....
```

and later

```
Hash hash;
string this_string;

...

hash[ this_string ]++;

...
```

which I did use often and with success.

Regards

rbo